# JQuery get list of all selected radio buttons

Tags: jquery, radio-button

```
var arrayradio = new Array();
$('.apply-filter-btn').off().click( function(){
  $(".radio-btn input:checked").each(function (index) {
    arrayradio[index] = $(this).val();
  });
  alert(arrayradio.length);
});
```

I create many radio buttons, all with the class name "radio-btn". If I click on another button with the class name "apply-filter-btn" I want to scan all radio buttons and get a list with all the selected radios. At the moment alert shows "0" even though radio btns are selected.

Comment: You don't really need the class if you want all radio buttons. Try this selector: " input[type='radio']:checked"

Comment: Thank you Nikkorian! That works, but I want to add other radio buttons that shouldn't be considered in that. Is there a way to consider only the radios with class "radio-btn" directly in the call? Why is $".radio-btn input[type='radio']:checked" not working?

Comment: The problem is that by putting a space between the class and the input you are telling jQuery that the input is a child of the element with the class. If all the selector components apply to the same elements,  you should  abutt them (no spaces) - e.g. present yours as  input[type='radio'].radio-btn:checked.

Comment: Note that when you chain selector components like this, the "type selector" (i.e. html element type - e.g. input) must come first.   A useful page is https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp